# SwiftUI: airdropping coredata object

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I wanted to ask if there is a way to airdrop a coredata object from one device to another.

How to share an NSManagedObject from one device via airdrop and then receive it and use it on the other device. Basically any device to a device

Comment: I'd share JSON instead. But you might need to recreate the "relations", so you might need to send also all the relations.